# react tabs call componentDidMount every time when switching tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using this react library: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs, I have created a simple Component like this:

```
export default class Sample extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Mount");
    }

    render () {
    return (

            <div>
             Hello
            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I have inserted it inside the tabs in my sample app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';
import Sample from './Sample.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  handleSelect(index, last) {
    console.log('Selected tab: ' + index + ', Last tab: ' + last);
  }

  render() {
    return (


      <Tabs
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        selectedIndex={2}
      >

        <TabList>

          <Tab>Foo</Tab>
          <Tab>Bar</Tab>
          <Tab>Baz</Tab>
        </TabList>

        <TabPanel>
          <Sample />
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <Sample />
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <Sample />
        </TabPanel>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And every time I switch Tab the `componentDidMount` is called and I can see the `Mount` log in the console. My question is how can avoid calling the `componentDidMount` method every time, but calling it only the first time? I make this question because I want add an Ajax call inside it and I don't want make the Ajax call every time I switch the tab, but only one time.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`forceRenderTabPanel={true}`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs#example) on the `<Tabs/>` component so that the tabs stay mounted.

```
<Tabs
  onSelect={this.handleSelect}
  selectedIndex={2}
  forceRenderTabPanel={true}
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes the forceRenderTabPanel mount only one time and doesn't unmount it, the problem is that the hidden tabs doesn't have the right style, for example the width in not loaded right. There is a way to reload style?

Comment: That's a CSS issue I assume. Styles don't need to be reloaded.

Comment: `forceRenderTabPanel={true}`, at least in my case, means the Ajax call is made when ANY tab is mounted, which is just not usable.

Comment: Same here using `forceRenderTabPanel={true}` means all tables are going to be loaded even if user did not clicked them so if you have a tab with big amount of data to be loaded this component will stay stuck until get that data even if the user does not need it.

Answer (score 2):

I have just had the same problem. All your components need to exist at the same time and use this.STATE.tabIndex and CSS to control the invisibility.

Create the Tabs with controlled mode:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { tabIndex: 0 };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs onSelect={tabIndex => this.setState({ tabIndex })}>
        <TabList>
          <Tab>Title 1</Tab>
          <Tab>Title 2</Tab>
        </TabList>
        <div style={this.state.tabIndex===0 ? 
          {display:"block"}: {display:"none"}} >
        </div>
        
        <div style={this.state.tabIndex===0 ? 
          {display:"block"}: {display:"none"}} >
        </div>

      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You cant get the same behavior with `forceRenderTabPanel={true}`

Comment: Only thing to remember here is not to use TabPanel & use Divs as above.

Answer (score 1):

Every time React adds a component to the DOM `componentDidMount`will fire, there is no way around that.

In your case, when you switch tabs, I assume that React *unmounts* the current content of the `TabPanel` component and *mounts* the new content, which is your `Sample` component, which in turn, once mounted, will fire the `componentDidMount` method.

Depending on what your AJAX call returns, you should probably rethink where to place the AJAX call.

Comment: And where I can place it?

Comment: I am assuming you are fetching the TabPanel contents right? So you could approach it with a couple of ways. One way to do it is to place the Ajax call in the componentDidMount of Tabs for example. In any case, check what the forceRenderTabPanel property of react-tabs does, as it may allow you to mount the tab contents only once, without unmounting

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes the forceRenderTabPanel mount only one time and doesn't unmount it, the problem is that the hidden tabs doesn't have the right style, for example the width in not loaded right. There is a way to reload style?

Comment: What do you mean that hidden tabs don't have the right style? Not being visible should be enough, no? In any case their style should be defined in the CSS, so I cannot imagine what the problem is here